# Null space and range of generic projection matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $v \in \Bbb R^2$ that is nonzero. I've already proved that $R(P_v) = Sp\{v\}$, but I need to find the null space of $P_v$, as well as the dimensions of the range and null space. How would I go about doing that?
($P_v = \frac{vv^T}{||v||^2}$).
I know the null space of $P_v$ = $\{x: P_vx = 0\} $, so it's $\{x: vv^Tx = 0\}$? I'm not sure where to go from here.
I also need to do the same problem but with $v \in \Bbb R^n$.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

As you have shown that the range of $P_v$ is the span of $v$, i.e. the line through the origin parallell to $v$, you know that the dimension of its range is $1$ ($v$ is a basis). This will be the case for $\mathbb{R}^n$. The range of $P_v$ is the column space $\text{Col}(P_v)$. Since $P_v = \frac{1}{\lVert v \rVert^2}vv^T$, its easy to see that all columns in $P_v$ are linear combinations of $v$, so $\text{Col}(P_v) = \mathbb{R}v$. Since you know the dimension of the column space, you know the dimension of the null space by the Rank-Nullity Theorem. So $\dim \text{Nul} (P_v) = n-1$.

You can also see this directly. Choose an orthogonal basis $\{v_1, \ldots v_n \}$ for $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $v_1 = v$. We claim that $\{v_2, \ldots v_n \} \subseteq \text{Nul} (P_v)$. This is easily varified:

$$P_v v_i = \frac{1}{\lVert v \rVert^2} (vv^T)v_i = \frac{1}{\lVert v \rVert^2} v(v^Tv_i) = \frac{v \cdot v_i}{\lVert v \rVert^2} v = 0$$

since $v_i$ is orthogonal to $v$ for $2 \leq i \leq n$. Hence, $\{ v_2, \ldots, v_n \}$ forms a basis for the null space of $P_v$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. How can we assume that the basis is orthogonal though?

Comment: That's a cogent question! First of all, just to make sure we are on the same page, we don't pick a basis at random and *assume* that it is orthogonal. We choose an orthogonal basis. But why can we always extend $v$ to an orthogonal basis? If you are familiar with the Gram-Schmidt process, you can argue with that. If not, you might just want to think geometrically about it. Imagine you are in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and see the vector $v$. What you can do is rotate the coordinate system (i.e. the standard basis) so that $e_1$ is parallell to $v$ and you have your new basis.